# How can I retrieve instance of last added item

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm, last-insert-id

I'm using github.com/jinzhu/gorm with a mysql backend.  I want to retrieve the Id (or the full entity) of the row in the previous Create call.

As in, last-insert-id: (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
type User struct {
  Id int
  Name string
}

user := User{Name: "jinzhu"}
db.Save(&user)
// user.Id is set to last insert id
```

Comment: I wasn't passing it as a pointer!  It works well now.
Meanwhile, thank you for a very useful library.

Answer (score 3):

Try as follows

```
type User struct {
  Id   int    `gorm:"column:id; PRIMARY_KEY" json:"id"`
  Name string `gorm:"column:name" json:"name"`
}

user := User{Name: "Andy"}
db.Save(&user)
// user.Id is set to last insert id
```

Comment: Can't we do this via db.Create?

Comment: @BalajiSrinivasan you can but Create insert the value into database and Save update value in database, if the value doesn't have primary key, will insert it