# gorm exec return ID from insert transaction with raw sql

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

I am using GORM to run SQL queries. I am trying to `Exec` an `INSERT` statement as a `TRANSACTION` because I need to be able to return the latest inserted ID.

Here is a code snippet:

```
query := `
        START TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO something (a, b, c)
            VALUES (@arg1, @arg2, @arg3);
            SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
        COMMIT;`
    result := DB.Exec(
        query,
        sql.Named("arg1", "aaa"),
        sql.Named("arg2", "bbb"),
        sql.Named("arg3", "ccc"),
    )
```

I've read through the GORM transactions docs, but the examples are wildly different than my use case.

My goal is to create an INSERT statement and finally return me the latest ID from that create. Using MySQL.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have experience with GORM but with plain SQL statements you can just get use `result.LastInsertId()`. See https://github.com/hectorcorrea/hectorcorrea.com/blob/main/models/blog.go#L115-L130 for an example.

Comment: What errors are you running into?

Comment: why dont you use query builder instead of raw? examle: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28776926/9984295

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know your exact usecase, it seems that here you're not really taking full advantage of GORM, and could benefit by using its methods.

```golang
type Something struct {
    ID int
    A  string
    B  string
}

something := Something{
    A: "Foo",
    B: "Bar",
}

db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    // save your item in the transaction (use 'tx' from this point, not 'db')
    if err := tx.Create(&something).Error; err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        // returning any error will rollback
        return err
    }

    // do anything else within the transaction...

    // return nil will commit the whole transaction
    return nil
})

fmt.Printf("%+v\n", something)
```

Afterwards, the original `something` variable will contain the ID that was just created:

```
{
  "ID": 26,
  "A": "Foo",
  "B": "Bar"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just do this example

```
     var ID int64
     tx.Raw("INSERT INTO yourTable (yourColumn) VALUES ('testInsertValue') RETURNING 
     id").Scan(&ID)
```

I use tx in assumption you have set your transaction into tx, you can do the transaction in many ways.
And for the return value, you can use your model's struct instead of just the var ID like the example.

thank you.